# Probability distribution function: $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

The probability distribution function of a random variable $X$ is given by $f(x).$ Another random variable $Y$ is related to $X$ by $Y=X^2.$

What is the probability of $Y$ being less than or equal to $b$ where $b\in[0,\infty)$

What I have done/ what I know,

EDIT

Using method of transformation suggested by @SeanRoberson,

\begin{align}P(X\le x) &= f(x) \\ 
P(Y\le b )&= P(X^2 \le b)\\
&= P(X \le b^{1/2}) \\
&=\int_0^{b^{1/2}}f(x)~ dx
\end{align}

Is this answer correct.?
and as the value of b is not given , numerical answer is not possible.

If I am missing something please help me .

Comment: Hint: the method of transformations.

Comment: Can you please provide me the answer with steps.?

Comment: Not until you show what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, Can you please have a look at the edits.?

Comment: @SeanRoberson. Helpful to point out it's not a one-to-one transformation, so usual 'transformation method' needs to be modified.

Comment: $P(X\le x)=F(x)$.  So $f(x)=F'(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

$P(X^2\le b)=P(-\sqrt{b}\le X\le\sqrt{b})=\int\limits_{-\sqrt{b}}^{\sqrt{b}}f(x)dx$.

You have to include case where $X$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your edits, showing your thoughts. This is not a 1 to 1 transformation.

Practical example:

Let $X\sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ $Y \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 1).$

Then $P(Y \le 3.8416)$ $= P(|X| \le 1.96)$ $= P(-1.96 \le X \le 1.96) \approx 0.95.$

In cae you're familiar with R statistical software, see below. If not look at printed tables of the standard normal CDF and of chi-squared distributions.

```
pchisq(3.8416, 1)
[1] 0.9500042
pnorm(1.96) - pnorm(-1.96)
[1] 0.9500042
```

Comment: Can you please have a look at my current edit. Please

Comment: I have looked at your edit. I do not wish to comment directly on the details of it. I hope you will look carefully at my answer.

Comment: Your most recent edit just showed on my screen. The third line is wrong. It should be something like $P(-b^{1/2} \le X \le b^{1/2} ).$ The lower limit on the integral in the last line needs to be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people are answering this without pointing out conspicuous problems with the way the question is phrased. You wrote:

> The probability distribution function of a random variable $X$ is given by $f(x).$

Usually "probability distribution function", if that term is used, means the cumulative distribution function (c.d.f.), often denoted by (capital) $F,$ so that you have $\Pr(X\le x) = F(x),$ and indeed you wrote $\Pr(X\le x) = f(x),$ suggesting that you intended $f$ to be the c.d.f. **But** then you wrote

> $$P(Y\le b )= \cdots =\int_0^{b^{1/2}}f(x)~ dx$$

suggesting you intended $f$ to be the probability density function (p.d.f.) instead.

Then there is also the fact that $\big[X^2\le b\big]$ is equivalent to $\big[ -\sqrt b \le X\le b\big].$

Comment: In one of his many books, Robert Bob Ash mentioned that to "specify" the distribution of a random variable meant one of several things: give its density function, or its distribution function, or give its measure, or give its Laplace transform, or give its Fourier transform, or given an algorithm on how to obtain it, and so on. After that, he kept using the phrase "distribution of random variable" to mean one of several things. If you have read the books of Ash, you will know that he is very serious about formality. (Just commenting.)

Comment: @WillM. : Indeed, one can specify a probability distribution in any of a number of ways. But one must not confuse them with each other.